# Using C++ how do I access data from a .txt file as part of a linked list when I have both integers and character arrays?

Tags: c++, io, doubly-linked-list

My problem is I have numbers of file type int as well as a char array of length 50 in a .txt file. I have a linked list (queue structured) program that is essentially an event calendar that has an index for searching a specific entry, the day of the week, a date, and a message (information about the event). Without reading from the file I can create events, delete events, modify events, display all the events or display a single event. What I need to add: 1. The ability to save all of the events when the program is terminated. 2. Then the next time it is opened I need to be able to read thee info from the .txt file and create a new event for each event in the .txt file. My text file entries.txt is shown right above the code. Each line is as follows: 1. Index, 2. Day of the week (Sunday=1), 3. Day, 4. Month, 5. Year, 6. Message. Below it shows each event on one line but in my .txt file each number/char is a new line.

1
4
22
4
2015
Baseball_game_at_7
2
3
13
3
2015
This_event_is_for_nothing
3
5
17
6
2015
Birthday

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class Event{
protected:
    int index;
    enum DAY{Sunday=1, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday};
    int date[3];
    char msg[50];
public:

    Event *next;
    Event *prev;

    Event(){
        next=NULL;
        prev=NULL;
    }

    int a;
    int day, day1;

    virtual void getindex(int b){   
        index=b;
    }

    virtual int getindex2(){
        a=index;
        return a;
    }

    virtual void getindex3(int c){
        index=c;
    }

    virtual void getday2(int d){
        day=d;
    }

    virtual void getdate2(int e, int f, int g){
        date[0]=e;
        date[1]=f;
        date[2]=g;
    }

    virtual void getmessage2(char h[50]){
        msg=h;
    }

        virtual void getdate(){
        cout<<"\nOptions:\n1. Sunday\n2. Monday\n3. Tuesday\n4. Wednesday\n5. Thursday\n6. Friday\n7. Saturday\nWhich day would you like to select (enter the day): ";
        cin>>day;   
        cout<<"Please enter the date you would like to use (In the form of dd mm yyyy): ";
        cin>>date[0];
        cin>>date[1];
        cin>>date[2];
    }

    virtual void getcurrentdate(){
        time_t now=time(0);
        tm *local=localtime(&now);
        time_t y=1900+local->tm_year;
        time_t m=1+local->tm_mon;
        time_t d=local->tm_mday;
        time_t day1=local->tm_wday;
        day=day1+1;
        date[0]=d;
        date[1]=m;
        date[2]=y;
        }

    virtual void getmessage(){
        cout<<"Please enter your message (Use _ for any spaces): ";
        cin>>msg;
    }

    virtual void display(){

        cout<<"\nThe index is: "<<index<<endl;
        switch(day){
        case Sunday:
            cout<<"The day of the week is: Sunday"<<endl;
            break;
        case Monday:
            cout<<"The day of the week is: Monday"<<endl;
            break;
        case Tuesday:
            cout<<"The day of the week is: Tuesday"<<endl;
            break;
        case Wednesday:
            cout<<"The day of the week is: Wednesday"<<endl;
            break;
        case Thursday:
            cout<<"The day of the week is: Thursday"<<endl;
            break;
        case Friday:
            cout<<"The day of the week is: Friday"<<endl;
            break;
        case Saturday:
            cout<<"The day of the week is: Saturday"<<endl;
            break;
        }
        cout<<"The date is: "<<date[0]<<"/"<<date[1]<<"/"<<date[2]<<endl;
        cout<<"The message is: "<<msg<<endl;
    }

};

 class Queue{

Event *Front, *Rear;

public:

Queue(){
        Front=NULL;
        Rear=NULL;
    }

int index;
int input4;

void newevent(int x){
        Event *temp;

        temp=new Event;

        if(Front==NULL){
                Front=temp;

                Rear=Front;
        temp->prev=NULL;
        }else{
                Rear->next=temp;
                temp->next=NULL;
        temp->prev=Rear;
        Rear=temp;
        }

    index=x;
    temp->getindex(index);
    cout<<"\nOptions:\n1. Enter a date manually\n2. Use the current system date and time\nWhat would you like to do: ";
    cin>>input4;
    switch(input4){
    case 1: // Get date manually
        temp->getdate();
        break;
    case 2: // Get current date
        temp->getcurrentdate();
        break;
    }
    temp->getmessage();
    temp->display();
    temp=NULL;
    }

int p;
Event *temp2;
void deleteevent(){
    Event *temp=Front;
    Front=temp->next;
    delete temp;
}

int c,d, input1, input3;
void modifyevent(int z){
    d=z;
    Event *temp=Front;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        for(c=1;c<d;c++){
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        input1=0;
        while(input1!=3){
            cout<<"\nOptions:\n1. Change the date\n2. Change the message\n3. exit\nWhat would you like to update: ";
            cin>>input1;
            switch(input1){
            case 1: // Change date
                cout<<"Options:\n1. Enter a date manually\n2. Use the current system date and time\nWhat would you like to do: ";
                cin>>input3;
                switch(input3){
                case 1: // Get date manually
                    temp->getdate();
                    break;
                case 2: // Get current date
                    temp->getcurrentdate();
                    break;
                }

                break;
            case 2: // Change message
                temp->getmessage();
                break;
            case 3: // Exit
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"You entered an invalid number!";
            }
        }
        temp=NULL;
    }
}

int e,f;
void display(int z){
    f=z;
    Event *temp=Front;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        for(e=1;e<f;e++){
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        temp->display();
        temp->next;
        temp=NULL;
    }
}


void displayall(){
        Event *temp=Front;
        while(temp!=NULL){
                temp->display();
                cout<<"\n";
                temp=temp->next;
        }
    }

int end;
int x;
int y;
int a;
int b;
int g[3];
char h[50];

void readfromfile(){ // This was my attempt at the problem
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("entries.txt");
    Event *temp;
    x=1;
    y=1;
    end=1;
    while(fin>>y){
        end++;          
    }
    for(x;x<end;x++) {  // till end-of-file
        a=fin>>x;
        x++;
        b=fin>>x;
        x++;
        g[0]=fin>>x;
        x++;
        g[1]=fin>>x;
        x++;
        g[2]=fin>>x;
        x++;
        h=fin.getline(x);

        temp=new Event;
            if(Front==NULL){
                    Front=temp;
                    Rear=Front;
            temp->prev=NULL;
            }else{
                    Rear->next=temp;
                    temp->next=NULL;
            temp->prev=Rear;
            Rear=temp;
            }
        temp->getindex3(a);
        temp->getday2(b);
        temp->getdate2(g[0],g[1],g[2]);
        temp->getmessage2(h);
        temp=NULL;
    }
    fin.close();
}

void writetofile(){ //I understand this is blank, I havn't made it this far

}
};


int main(){
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("entries.txt", ios::app);


cout<<"\nWELCOME TO YOUR EVENT PLANNER\n";

Queue a;
a.readfromfile();
int inp=0;
    int i=0;
int num=4;
    int type;
int counter=0;
int displayevent, modifyevent;
while(inp!=6){
        cout<<"\nOptions:\n1. Create new event\n2. Delete the oldest event\n3. Modify an event\n4. Display all events\n5. Display a specific event\n6. Exit event planner\nWhat do you want to do: ";
        cin>>inp;
        switch(inp){
        case 1: // New event
        a.newevent(num);
        num++;
        counter++;
            break;
        case 2: // Delete event
        a.deleteevent();
        counter--;
            break;
    case 3: // Modify event
        cout<<"\nEnter the index of the event you would like to modify: ";
        cin>>modifyevent;
        a.modifyevent(modifyevent);
        break;
    case 4: // Display all events
        a.displayall();
            break;

        case 5: //Display single event
        cout<<"\nEnter the index of the event you would like to display: ";
        cin>>displayevent;
        a.display(displayevent);
        break;
    case 6: // Exit event planner
        break;
    default:
        cout<<"You entered an invalid number"; 
        break;
        }
    }   

cout<<"The current number of events is "<<counter<<endl;

myfile.close();


return 0;
}
```

Queue.readfromfile() was my attempt at reading the file and inputting each event in the file as a new event. I need to know how to get each line of the text file saved as something different so it can be sent to a function in the class above.
Queue.writetofile() was intentionally left blank because I haven't even made it that far yet. I should be able to figure it out pretty easily. I wanted to finish reading files first.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please state a clearly defined problem you found with your code. Please reduce your code to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `virtual void getmessage2(char h[50])` <- the `50` there does not do what you might think it does. Use `std::string` for strings, but if you need raw arrays, make sure to pass the size.

Comment: Please search StackOverflow for "c++ read file columns".  There are too many of these already.

Comment: Hmmm, I suggest you overload `operator>>` to input your data members.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by using the built-in getline() function to convert each line of the file into a string, then parse each string individually. You may also want to consider using delimiters inside the input file to help with the parsing process.

EDIT: Here is an example from a program i wrote a couple of months ago. The program finds all the possible ways in which a list of songs can be arranged on one or more LP records. This is the part of the program that parses the input file:

```cpp
vector<song> songs;
string input, title, min, sec, infile;
ifstream inputStream;

cout << endl << "Enter input file name:" << endl;
getline(cin, infile);

inputStream.open(infile, ios::in);

while (inputStream.good() && !inputStream.eof())
{
    getline(inputStream, input);

    input = regex_replace(input, regex("^\\s+"), "");
    input = regex_replace(input, regex("\\s+"), " ");

    if (input != "" && input[0]!='#') // # symbol can be used to comment out lines in the input file
    {
        title = input.substr(0, input.find_last_of(" "));
        min = input.substr(title.length() + 1, input.find_last_of(":") - input.find_last_of(" ") - 1);
        sec = input.substr(title.length() + min.length() + 2, input.length() - (title.length() + min.length() + 2));
        songs.push_back(song(title, stoi(min), stoi(sec)));
    }
}

inputStream.close();
```

The calls to regex_replace are just to remove any unintentional whitespace padding from the data (not important if the input file is guaranteed to not have excess padding). The important part is that i am using getline(inputStream, input) to retrieve the data in the file one line at a time, then using the .substr() function of std::string to parse the data on the delimiter (not necessary if you know the exact length of the data being parsed).

For reference, here is how the input file is formatted:

```
Custard Pie 4:13
The Rover 5:37
In My Time of Dying 11:04
Houses of the Holy 4:02
Trampled Under Foot 5:37
Kashmir 8:32
In the Light 8:46
Bron-Yr-Aur 2:06
Down by the Seaside 5:13
Ten Years Gone 6:32
Night Flight 3:36
The Wanton Song 4:10
Boogie with Stu 3:53
Black Country Woman 4:24
Sick Again 4:42
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't search StackOverflow, I will give you a synopsis of how to input your stuff.

### Let the Object read its data members.

There several methods on how to do this, but we'll stick with overloading the extraction operator.

```
class Event
{
private:
  int index;
  int day_of_week;
  unsigned int day;
  unsigned int month;
  unsigned int year;
  std::string message;  // Don't use char array here.
public:
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inp, Event& e);
};

std::istream&
operator>>(std::istream& inp, Event& e)
{
  inp >> e.index;
  inp >> e.day_of_week >> e.day >> e.month >> e.year;
  std::getline(inp, e.message);
  return inp;
}
```

To read an `Event` your code fragment would look like:

```
  Event e;
  my_input_file >> e;
```

### Reading and storing many objects

Your loop for reading in many `Event`s would look like:

```
  std::vector<Event> event_container;
  Event single_event;
  while (my_input_file >> single_event)
  {
    event_container.push_back(single_event);
  }
```

### A Linked List of Events

A linked list is a container and can be reused for different objects.
To create a linked list of events, you should use `std::list`:

```
  std::list<Event> event_container;
  Event            single_event;
  while (my_input_file >> single_event)
  {
    event_container.push_back(single_event);
  }
```

### Linked List Class Assignment

If you happen to need to write a Linked List due to a class assignment, you should isolate the implementation of the list from the data:

```
struct Node
{
  Node(Element * p_data = NULL)
  : p_element(p_data), next(NULL)
  { ; }
  Element * p_element;
  Node *    next;
};

struct Element_Linked_List
{
  Node *  p_head;
  Node *  p_tail;
  Element_Linked_List()
    : p_head(NULL), p_tail(NULL)
  { ; }
};
```

By loosely coupling the data (`Element`) from the container, you will be able to use this linked list in other assignments coming up.

### Extending Encapsulation -- A date class

I recommend you take this a step further a move some of the workload and complexity to a `Date` class.

```
struct Date_DoW
{
  static const char dow_names[] =
  {
    "Day Of Rest", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",    "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday",
  }
  enum Day_Of_Week {Monday = 1, Tuesday, Wednesday,
                    Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday};
private:
  void print_dow_name(Day_Of_Week dow, std::ostream& out)
  {
    out << dow_names(dow);
  }
  // etc...
};
```

You would augment the class above for days, months and years.

An advantage to refactoring the date as a separate object, is that you can test it separately, get it working, and not have to recompile it.  You can also reuse it in other assignments.